# Вывод пользователей по дате загрузки

Tags: php, wordpress

В админке wordpress реализована возможность загрузки новых пользователей с помощью библиотеки PHPExcel из файла xlsx.
 Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы можно было просматривать загруженных пользователей по количествам загрузок в один день? Т.е. чтобы можно было отсортировать всех пользователей, которые загружены в один день но в разное время. За одну загрузку может быть импортировано разное количество пользователей.
Я делал так:
массив $users, это уже загруженные пользователи, полученные из бд:

```
$users = $wpdb->get_results($query, 'ARRAY_A');
```

```
foreach($users as $user){
    $date = explode(' ',$user['user_registered'])[0];
    unset($user['user_registered']);
    $userData[$date][] = $user;
}
```

Но так пользователи только сортируются по определённому дню.
А в один день может быть несколько загрузок. Подскажите, как отсортировать пользователей по количествам загрузок в день?

Comment: А в таблице с пользователями есть вообще что-нибудь про время создания пользователей? Или вы не смотрели даже?

Comment: это стандартная таблица wp_users, да, там есть поле user_registered в котором есть время загрузки. Но время начала и завершения одной загрузки может быть разное, из-за большого количества загружаемых пользователей

Comment: разница времени начала и завершения одной загрузки может быть в несколько секунд или несколько минут

Comment: нужно, чтобы приведенный выше код $userData[$date][] = $user; заменить на что-то такое:

Comment: $userData[$upload] = $user;

Comment: >А в таблице с пользователями есть вообще что-нибудь про время создания пользователей? Или вы не смотрели даже?

Comment: в коде как-бы видно, что я использую поле user_registered

Comment: поле "user_registered" содержит такой формат даты: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Comment: может нужно сделать какое-то дополнительное поле в таблице wp_users, в котором будет какой-то ключ, идентифицирующий одну конкретную загрузку? т.е. чтобы можно было отличить одну загрузку от другой

Comment: Если вы готовы видоимзенять БД, то конечно это будет оптимальный вариант. Просто учитывайте, что потом это может требовать дополнительного внимания при обновлениях движка, например. Вообще же, в WP есть функционал мета данных, насколько я помню, попробуйте что-то узнать про него - он может позволить прикреплять к сущностям базы свои доп. поля без внесения изменений в саму БД

Comment: > Вообще же, в WP есть функционал мета данных, насколько я помню, попробуйте что-то узнать про него - он может позволить прикреплять к сущностям базы свои доп. поля без внесения изменений в саму БД

Comment: Про эти метаполя знаю. Я и хочу узнать совета, как правильней сделать.
Если использовать метаполе, тогда как это поле нужно идентифицировать и как его определить перед загрузкой?
Т.е. при загрузке пользователей из файла xlsx идёт цикл, выбирающий по одному пользователю в одной итерации. 
Как посоветуете задать новое метаполе, чтобы при новой загрузке это метаполе отличалось от уже имеющихся метаполей при предыдущей загрузке?

Comment: Получается, перед основным циклом загрузки пользователей нужно сначала делать запрос в базу данных, чтобы узнать предыдущее значение метаполя, и задать при текущей загрузке новое метаполе, которое отличается от предыдущего?

Comment: Вот тут уже извините, не смогу помочь. Если бы я знал ответ настолько хорошо, то я написал бы его как ответ, а не попытался помочь вам в комментариях к вопросу ;)